# The end of my video gets cut off every time I finalize

Tags: final-cut-pro

I have a video that I have edited and saved as mp4 several times, each time the last few seconds gets cut off.  The frame freezes but I hear the sound, and the closing credits are cut off.  Same result on a 30 minute version and 15 minute edited version.

Answer (score 0):

**You might want to check the framerate of your video and the one of your composition and match it.**

If they don't match the app will try to fill the timeline of the composition with footage that is 'shorter' in terms of frames per seconds.

Answer (score 0):

have you cut the video stream without re-encoding it? You might check your group-of-pictures settings.
I only know this effect when cropping some seconds at the beginning of videos: When the first I-Frame is cropped, the video-stream only appears after the next I-Frame - this can take many seconds...